# Was Germany responsible for WW1?

Tags: world-war-one

I know that the US, England, and France  decided that Germany was responsible for WW1, but was this a fair assessment?  Why/why not?

Comment: @Tyler, so what you're saying is that I should edit my question as to make the answer I got not make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The question of responsibility for the *first* World War is sufficiently unclear to count as "primarily opinion-based". Most nations could have acted better, and who was worst is a value judgement.

Comment: The origins of the First World War are extraordinarily complex. There were inherent long-term reasons, and issues that lit the fuse. But the essential problem was Germany's late industrialisation, and her late unification as a nation state (1870s). There were also massive issues concerning a myriad of nationalisms within the Austro_Hungarian Empire and in the Balkans, as countries like Serbia fought off the Ottoman Turks, and *Pan-Slavisim* took root. Germany's  imperial ambitions could not be accommodated within the existing states system. 1914-18 was essentially a war of empires.