# Is Germany to blame for WW1?

Tags: germany, world-war-one

Germany turned a local conflict between Austria-Hungary and Russia into a world war. Isn't Germany the responsible party here? I know this is an opinion but teachers told me that I make a good point. Does anyone agree with this? Why/ why not?

Comment: The community frowns strongly on "Please do my homework for me" questions. Try digging up a copy of *Barbara W. Tuchman's* **The Guns of August** for a good background introduction.

Comment: This is not a "please do my homework for me" question. I am asking for help, not asking directly for answers from an individual. For @PieterGeerkens

Comment: This question would be improved if you cited your prior research.  BBC History magazine did an entire issue on this six or 8 months ago - you might consult that.

Comment: @Peter Geerkins: Tuchman is indeed a good source. Can you offer a comparable source written by a German-speaking person?

Comment: In fact, this is actually a [dup](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/26049/was-germany-responsible-for-ww1) of a [dup](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/813/why-was-germany-held-accountable-for-ww1). **I've started a [meta question on this](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/2256/germany-caused-wwi-questions)**.

Comment: [ask] establishes that this is not a forum for  opinion questions.

Comment: The question explicitly solicits opinions (in the style of a typical essay question...) which isn't what H.SE do here. However, I will point out that the premise is very one sided and factually flawed. One could just as well argue that *Russia* turned a local conflict between Austria-Hungary and Serbia into a world war. Russia was allied with France explicitly against Germany; its intervention in the Balkans against Austria - Germany's only real ally - is not really "local".

Comment: 'The First World War' by John Keegen is also a good source for this theme. It is also easy to read considering the complexity of the matter. No wiki link for this book. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Keegan

Answer (score 2):

The question is controversial, in the sense that different modern historians express different opinions. Most maintain that several parties are responsible to some extent. As there is no objective criterion for the "share of responsibility" probably this question will be never settled. One also has to take into account that most modern histories of WWI are written by English-speaking historians.
(I will be grateful if someone points to me a serious comprehensive history of WWI
written by a modern German historian). On my own opinion, Russia's and Austria's part is at least as large as the German one.

"Germany turned a local conflict between Austria-Hungary and Russia into a world war". This is certainly wrong. Germany had an obligation to defend Austria in the case of a Russian attack, and Austria counted on this when it attacked Serbia. Similarly, Russia felt obliged to defend Serbia, and France had an obligation to help Russia. So from the very beginning, all understood that this is not a "local conflict". So one can say that "Russia turned a local conflict (between Austria and Serbia) into a world war. But of course this also would be an oversimplification.

As a serious research of the Russian role I can recommend S. McMeekin, Russian origins of the first world war, Cambridge 2011.

Comment: True, but when ArchDuke Franz Ferdinand was assassinated, why did Germany come to a rush in the war between Austria-Hungary and Serbia?

Comment: As far as I know, Germany did not "rush to the war"  but only guaranteed Austria's protection. Then Russia mobilized. It was the first to mobilize. Many think that it was this mobilization that triggered the world war. But as I said the issue is still controversial. Look at the exact chronology of events.

Comment: I agree, but do you know why Germany felt the need to protect Austria-Hungary if it was just a local-conflict? I see eye to eye to you with everything else, but that is my one concern.

Comment: @Mags: just because Austro-Hungaria was afraid of the Russian reaction. And Germany was afraid of the Russian army modernization. And Serbian answer to the Austrian ultimatum was given with a view of Russian support. From the very beginning it was clear that this is potentially not a local conflict.

Comment: Archduke Franz Ferdinand's assassination was the "beginning" of WW2. Wouldn't that count as between Austria-Hungary and Serbia? I agree with you to a point and then you lose me.

Comment: @Mags Germany was allied to Austria. Russia was allied to France against Germany. If Germany lets Russia take out Austria, who will stand with Germany when Russia and France attacks? Strategic concerns dictated that Germany had to protect Austria.

Comment: Russians supported the Serbs. Serbs killed Austrian Crown Prince. Germany was allied to Austria and already aware of her inability to fight a war on two-fronts without allies. What was Germany supposed to do?